# Removing duplicate elements from bidemensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I have 2 arrays: 1 that holds file names that contain an ID in the name and 2 that contains some data as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => 103135_cara.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file] => 103135_corpo.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [file] => 103136_cara.jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [file] => 103136_corpo.jpg
        )


Array2
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 103137
            [nome] => Eduardo Vieira
            [sexo] => 1
            [datanascimento] => 1983-11-15
            [morada] => R: Gothard Kaesemodel 750 ? Torre 1 - Ap 508
            [localidade] => Joinville
            [cp1] => 
            [cp2] => 
            [tlm] => 479946464
            [email] => eduardo@wetzel.com.br
            [estadocivil] => 1
            [profissao] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 103138
            [nome] => João Nuno Gonçalves
            [sexo] => 1
            [datanascimento] => 1984-08-13
            [morada] => Rua Elias Garcia Nº325 6D
            [localidade] => Amadora
            [cp1] => 2700
            [cp2] => 323
            [tlm] => 964359799
            [email] => joaoridebmx@yahoo.com
            [estadocivil] => 1
            [profissao] => 7
        )
```

I have merged the arrays into:

```
Array3
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 103137
            [nome] => Eduardo Vieira
            [sexo] => 1
            [datanascimento] => 1983-11-15
            [morada] => R: Gothard Kaesemodel 750 ? Torre 1 - Ap 508
            [localidade] => Joinville
            [cp1] => 
            [cp2] => 
            [tlm] => 479946464
            [email] => eduardo@wetzel.com.br
            [estadocivil] => 1
            [profissao] => 7
            [file1] => 103137_cara.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 103137
            [nome] => Eduardo Vieira
            [sexo] => 1
            [datanascimento] => 1983-11-15
            [morada] => R: Gothard Kaesemodel 750 ? Torre 1 - Ap 508
            [localidade] => Joinville
            [cp1] => 
            [cp2] => 
            [tlm] => 479946464
            [email] => eduardo@wetzel.com.br
            [estadocivil] => 1
            [profissao] => 7
            [file1] => 103137_cara.jpg
            [file2] => 103137_corpo.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 103138
            [nome] => João Nuno Gonçalves
            [sexo] => 1
            [datanascimento] => 1984-08-13
            [morada] => Rua Elias Garcia Nº325 6D
            [localidade] => Amadora
            [cp1] => 2700
            [cp2] => 323
            [tlm] => 964359799
            [email] => joaoridebmx@yahoo.com
            [estadocivil] => 1
            [profissao] => 7
            [file1] => 103138_cara.jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 103138
            [nome] => João Nuno Gonçalves
            [sexo] => 1
            [datanascimento] => 1984-08-13
            [morada] => Rua Elias Garcia Nº325 6D
            [localidade] => Amadora
            [cp1] => 2700
            [cp2] => 323
            [tlm] => 964359799
            [email] => joaoridebmx@yahoo.com
            [estadocivil] => 1
            [profissao] => 7
            [file1] => 103138_cara.jpg
            [file2] => 103138_corpo.jpg
        )
```

My question is: how can I remove the the array elements that contain only the key 'file1' keeping the ones that have both keys 'file1' and 'file2'

Here is the code I used to merge the arrays:

```
foreach ($ids as $val1) {
  foreach ($files as $key => $val2) {
    $cara = strpos($val2['file'], $val1['id'].'_cara');
    if ($cara !== false) {
      $val1['file1'] = $val2['file'];
      $data[] = $val1;
      unset($files[$key]);
    }
    $corpo = strpos($val2['file'], $val1['id'].'_corpo');
    if ($corpo !== false) {
      $val1['file2'] = $val2['file'];
      $data[] = $val1;
      unset($files[$key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you merge the arrays? I'm really not seeing where the duplicate entries appeared from or how the data relates. I mean you *could* just `foreach ($array as $key => $item) { if (!isset($item['file1'], $item['file2'])) { unset($array[$key]); } }` - but I think a better solution would be stop the dupes appearing in the first place.

Comment: For each entry in array2 (which holds the ID that is part of the file names in array1), there can be 1 or 2 entries in array1. There will be almost always 2 files for each array1 element.

Comment: I have tried this for the merging. I think here is my problem:
($ids is array1 and $files is array2)

Comment: foreach ($ids as $val1) 
{
    foreach ($files as $key => $val2) 
 {
        $cara = strpos($val2['file'],$val1['id'].'_cara');
  if($cara !== false) 
  {
   $val1['file1'] = $val2['file'];
   $data[] = $val1;
   unset($files[$key]);
  }
  $corpo = strpos($val2['file'],$val1['id'].'_corpo');
  if($corpo !== false) 
  {
   $val1['file2'] = $val2['file'];
   $data[] = $val1; 
   unset($files[$key]);
  }
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $nr => $values){
  if (isset($values['file1']) && !isset($values['file2']){
        unset($array[$nr]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function filter($element) {
    $result = isset($element['file1'], $element['file2']);

    return $result;
}

$out = array_filter($arr3, 'filter');
var_dump($out);
```

where $arr3 is your 3rd array

array_filter accept also methods as filter function: ex

```
array_filter($arr3, array('class_name or class instance', 'method_name'));
```

//edited
I used DaveRandom suggestion about isset

Comment: `isset()` accepts multiple arguments, and the `$result` variable is pointless. Just `return isset($element['file1'], $element['file2']);`

Comment: I forgot about isset - thanks. In my opinion construction like return isset($a, $v, $c) are difficult to examine with debugger - temporary variable is cheap.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way, probably run a loop and check if key 'file1' exist and key 'file2' not:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    if (isset($val['file1']) && !isset($val['file2'])) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your IDs in the original array appear to be unique (being that they are IDs, and all), it makes sense to use them for the keys. This would mean that you are easily able to identify the element to which each file belongs.

It's easy enough to re-index the array with the IDs as the keys:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($ids as $val) {
  $data[$val['id']] = $val;
}
```

Then in order to associate the files with the appropriate item, all you need to do is this:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {

  // First get the ID of the associated item
  $parts = explode('_', $file);
  $id = $parts[0];

  // Now add this file to the correct item
  // Find the next spare file number for this ID
  for ($i = 1; isset($data[$id]['file'.$i]); $i++) {
    continue;
  }
  // ...and add the file
  $data[$id]['file'.$i] = $file;

}
```

This will avoid producing the duplicate items in the first place. It also avoids the nested `foreach` - in general, if you find yourself doing this you've done something wrong. This is not a hard and fast rule, but it's generally only useful/the right way to do it if what you are doing is calculating possible permutations of multiple data sets, and this is not what you are doing here.

Now, I have to say that I would not do what you have done and create `file1` and `file2`, I would create a sub-array `files` instead. This will make it much easier to loop the files at a later time, and it will also avoid that check to find the next available number for the file.

So, I would make that second loop look like this:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {

  // First get the ID of the associated item
  $parts = explode('_', $file);
  $id = $parts[0];

  // Now add this file to the correct item
  if (!isset($data[$id]['files'])) {
    $data[$id]['files'] = array();
  }
  $data[$id]['files'][] = $file;

}
```